# Check if <ul> has less than 3 <li> items and apply CSS style

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the width of the ul li items, when there is less than 3 li items inside the UL. This is what I created, but it's not working properly, can you help me fix it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($('ul.products li').length <= 3) {
  $($this).css('width', '29%'); 
}})
```

The site is http://www.demo.simplexweb.dk/shopdemo1/ . It is related to the section with 3 products. If someone add a new products, the css should be different.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: You might need to post your html as well so we can see how your html is structured and we would know what `.products` is.

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please post your HTML and CSS. You likely don’t need JavaScript for this.

Comment: `$($this).css('width', '29%');` should be `$('ul.products').css('width', '29%'); `

Comment: You should have gotten an error saying  `Error: '$this' is undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with css only like so :

```
 li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(2),
 li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(1){width: 50%;}
```

if it's the first of it's type and second to last of it's type that's means if these two condition are true so there is only two element for this type, then you can apply `width: 50%;`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw05pc1/2/)**

try to add an other `li` element to the `ul` and the style will not work

and this is exactly what you need for your task :

```
li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(2),
 li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(1){

    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}

li:only-of-type{  // this to still apply the style if the element is only of it's type

    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;

}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw05pc1/2/)**

Now you can style the `li's` element inside the `ul` only if there is less then 3 `li's` without any `javascript`

## EDIT

**for less or equivalent to 3** `li's` :

```
 li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(3),
 li:nth-of-type(3):nth-last-of-type(1),
 li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2){width: 50%; background-color: black;}

 li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(2),
 li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(1){width: 50%; background-color: black;}

li:only-of-type{

    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;

}
```

**for less or equivalent to 4** `li's` :

```
 li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(4),
 li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(3),
 li:nth-of-type(3):nth-last-of-type(2),
 li:nth-of-type(4):nth-last-of-type(1){width: 50%; background-color: black;}

 li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(3),
 li:nth-of-type(3):nth-last-of-type(1),
 li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2){width: 50%; background-color: black;}

 li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(2),
 li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(1){width: 50%; background-color: black;}

li:only-of-type{

    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;

}
```

Comment: check the second live demo it don't fail if one element i'm pretty sure !

Comment: I wrote my coment based on the previous answer... It's ok now :-)

Comment: Very nice solution, but what happens if I would like it less than 3 or equivalent?

Comment: less then 3 it will still apply your css too

Comment: just test the demo in the fiddle  you'll see that if you add more than 2 li's it will fail but if you have less then 3 li's it will not fail

Comment: if you have understand the logic you will be able to do it the way you want